# How can I find matches between two tables using Hive?

Tags: hive, nested-loops

I am trying to find matches between two tables of URLs using Hive :

```
blacklist.url      siem.url

a.com              d.fr
b.net              f.es
c.ru               a.com
...                ...
```

When using :

```
SELECT blacklist.url FROM blacklist 
INNER JOIN siem ON (blacklist.url = siem.url);
```

I get no match (the only case where I have a match is when I put "a.com" on the same row of the two tables, e.g. when the siem table looks like {a.com,...,...} in my example).

So I was thinking I could use a nested loop of this form:

```
for each line1 in blacklist do
    for each line2 in siem do
        if line1 = line 2
            then print line1
```

I couldn't find any documentation in the Apache LanguageManual for nested loops and very few on condition statements so if anyone has an idea it would be of great help.

Comment: Your original INNER JOIN query should work, there must be another issue going on. are you sure the `a.com` strings are identical in each table? Can you show your `CREATE TABLE` statements?

Comment: There's no such things as loops in Hive.  If you do the `join` and it returns nothing, then there were no matches.